# Devise signing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

last time, I asked this question I have been misunderstood. So:

In my Rails3 application I use Devise for authentication. I have requirement which says, that every user can be logged in only from one browser. It means if user A is logged in (e.g. on FF), and then from other computer, or from other browser (e.g. Chrome) comes request to log user A, the first one should be logged out.

I found out, that I can override SessionController and it's create method. However I don't see any way to check if user with given email (params[:email]) is currently logged in, furthermore I don't know which method should I invoke to destroy this user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just store a timestamp for each page load in the session. Compare this in a before_filter with a last_seen field of user. If the user last seen is after the session timestamp destroy the user session.

Comment: Great and simple idea. In my version: for every user instance of user model keep timestamp when user with given login have logged in. In addition, for every user session keep timestamp as well. With every action, check if timestamp in model equals timestamp in session. If not - destroy user session.

But... how can I check in create function of SessionsController if given post form have right datas (email+password is correct)?

But...

Comment: The authentication of session is handled by devise and you shouldn't need to modify that for your requirement. I would just put the before_filter in application_controller.rb and not modify devise.

Comment: I found other way - we can inherit from Devise::SessionsController and override its after_sign_in_path_for action. Next, I noticed, that the field which says when user was lastly signing in is currently in default devise user model (current_user.current_sign_in_at)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you but what I'm recommending is that you check if the current user has been active on another browser and if they have, destroy the session on the current browser. This would be a before filter and invisible to the user.

Comment: Yeah, you're right:) I described the action which is executing to choose the user, that should be destroyed. You described the action which is executing to destroy the user:) Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take would be to modify the trackable or lastseen plugin and then use a warden callback.

https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Callbacks

Not a great answer, but maybe can get you started.